# GORM/Grails :: possible to query based on contents of a List within the model?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Assume the following:

```
class Thing {

    String name
    List<String> tags

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false)
        tags(nullable: false)
    }

}
```

I want to know if its possible, using GORM, to run a query for domain instances based on values in their respective lists

For instance: Are there dynamic GORM finders to query things like 'Find all Things that have the tag "Video" ', or 'Find all things with name = "Product1" that have the tag "Image" '

Just want to know if there's a nice concise way of doing this with Grails&Gorm, as opposed to retrieving a list of Things and iterating through it, finding the ones that have the appropriate tags and adding them to a results list.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth adding that we are using MongoDB, not traditional mysql, so as far as i understand HQL is not an option? (again i may be mistaken)

Comment: You're right, HQL (Hibernate Query Language) is only for traditional relational/SQL databases. BTW, Grails have GORM plugin for MongoDB as well

Answer (score 1):

One way (although not necessarily the most efficient!) would be to return the whole list of `Thing`s eg `Thing.list()` and then filter the resulting list using `findAll`.

`List results = Thing.list().findAll{it.tags.contains("Image")}`

How big is your list of `Thing`s and associated `Tag`s likely to be?